# Save a canvas image to disk

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Using js I was able to create a small script that is able to create random canvas images.
To transform them to png I do the following:

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
window.open(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
```

This is fine for seeing the images in a separate browser tab, but I'd like it to save it to disk whenever I run the program. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: can you save it in a cookie or in a db I mean all you need is the string from dataURL

Comment: Unfortunately I won't be using a db for this since the idea is to save the image and then upload it somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution! Node apparently supports canvas and allows for saving the image to filesystem via fs.
See here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3c2EFpCr_vY

Comment: Can you summarize the important parts of the YT link, preferably with a complete code snippet? Links can go down over time, and answers should stand on their own. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a link with the dataUrl als url and click on it virtually like so:

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>

<script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

  ctx.rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'pink'
  ctx.fill();

  function download() {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = 'filename.png';
    link.href = document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL('image/png')
    link.click();
  }

  download();

</script>
```

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/b7xpta0e/5/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However when I run it it prompts me to download the image when what I really needed was to save it right away to a folder in my disk. Is this even possible with javascript? Or do I need something like an expressjs server on my localhost with an endpoint to save images?

Comment: @Ress It's outside of JavaScripts capabilities to read/write to any file on the local computer unless permission is explicitly declared by the user (that popup you get when downloading, for example). [This is a good question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/201208/why-do-browsers-disallow-accessing-files-from-local-file-system-even-if-the-htmln) that shows why JavaScript is like this.

Comment: yeah, think if you could modify a user's whole file system in js how that would be so malicious.

Comment: @Stephen sounds about right, I don't know what I expected. Is there any way around this? Would it be possible to create a server using expressjs for example that had a post endpoint that received a base64 string and code convert to image and save locally?